# PRISM Silverlight 4 MEF - IActiveAware

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, prism

I am unable to get my ViewModel to receive the IActiveAware notification.

My view is registered with the region via View Discovery.

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(
    RegionNames.ListRegion, typeof(AlarmListView));
```

And the ViewModel implements IActiveAware, but this never gets set when the view becomes active. What am I missing?

My view-model is registered like so:

```
/// <summary>The alarm list view model.</summary>
[Export(typeof(IAlarmListViewModel))]
public class AlarmListViewModel :
    AsyncNotificationObject,
    IActiveAware,
    IAlarmListViewModel { ... }
```

and imported into the view like so:

```
[Import]
public IAlarmListViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return (IAlarmListViewModel)DataContext;
    }
    set
    {
        DataContext = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your view model registered?

Comment: What control is your ListRegion mapped to? I believe it's up to that to call the activate/deactivate as various control have different concepts on what can be active.

Comment: @CodeNAked: I'm using the ContentControl

Answer (score 0):

I guess `IsActive` will be changed only when you navigate to your view via `_regionManager.RequestNavigate` or `_region.Activate(view)`. In your case you can set `IsActive` on `view.Loaded` or `view.GotFocus` events.